# agm direction build type r error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 .
every thing works fine with ng serve & ng build but with ng build --prod the map doesn't open and has this **type r is not a constructor** in console.

im usning agm direction https://github.com/explooosion/Agm-Direction/

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="13">
      <agm-direction [waypoints]="waypoints" [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination">
      </agm-direction>
  </agm-map>


 this.origin = { lat: 18.544405, lng: 73.735341 };
    this.destination = { lat: 18.544405, lng: 73.735341 };
    this.waypoints = [
      {
        location: "18.532667,73.8276983"
      },
      {
        location: "18.533654,73.8235143"
      },
      {
        location: "18.523258, 73.762949"
      }
    ];
```

Comment: I created a stackblitz and can't recreate your error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en2dya?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts Can you please add more code from your files? Alternatively try updating your versions to the ones being used in the demo.

Comment: its a build error that to in prod i'm not sure how stackblitz is going to help

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon the same error, turns out the error is caused by [Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) (*which is enabled by default for production deployment*)

One solution would be to *disable* [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler):

```
ng build --prod --aot false
```

Another solution would be to wait until this error will be resolved in [`Agm-Direction` library](https://github.com/explooosion/Agm-Direction)

Here is the list of changes to resolve this issue:

1) Disable FESM via removing the following from `tsconfig.es5.json`

```
"flatModuleOutFile": "agm-direction.js",
"flatModuleId": "agm-direction"
```

2) modify `gulpfile.js` by replacing the line (for `copy:build` task)

```
return gulp.src([`${buildFolder}/**/*`, `!${buildFolder}/**/*.js`])
```

with

```
return gulp.src([`${buildFolder}/**/*`])
```